# Facebook Login + Google Login + Braintree Paypal Payment - AppDelegate issue

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-login, braintree, google-signin

My app has google sign in, facebook sign in and braintree integration.

I have put the following code in appdelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let checkFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let checkGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
    return checkGoogle || checkFB
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.release.braintreepayments") == .orderedSame {
        return BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)
    }
    return false
}
```

As I put the `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {}`, my sign in's stop working, and if I comment this out,sign in works fine. Can you tell me how to combine both? I am sure there is some conflict in choosing one of both methods, but I need both.

I have contacted Braintree Support for the same too.

Comment: Assume both delegate methods get fired ?

Comment: Both are not getting fired. Only the 2nd one gets fired during google sign in. Can we combine both these methods?

Comment: why are you always returning false in second method ?

Comment: That method returns true only if Braintree paypal payment is selected

Comment: Yeah I missed that. Anyhow which ios version are you checking this on. Did you know your first method is deprecated in ios 9 ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application

Comment: using iOS 11. So what should the ideal method be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use just second one:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.release.braintreepayments") == .orderedSame {
        return BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)
    }

    guard let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String else {
            return false
        }
    let annotation =  options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]

    let checkFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let checkGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

    return checkFB || checkGoogle

}
```